# Proxy support for OidcProfileCreator and OidcAuthenticator

Tags: pac4j

There's no proxy support for OidcAuthenticator and OidcProfileCreator in /callback api. I've requirement where okta can be accessible by internal proxies. We do have support for proxy in ResourceRetriever. Does anyone know if we can use proxy.

Proxy support in okta authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For the `OidcAuthenticator` and `OidcProfileCreator`, you need to set up the proxy at the JVM level.